# Forward slash in rest call using angularjs client and Flask server

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, rest, flask

I'm am calling a REST Flask server from an AngularJs client.
In one call, one of my ids (key) can contain a forward slash

If not, the call works fine.
If there's a slash, I receive a 404 not found error

I've tried to encode the key (encodeURIComponent), escape the key (escape)... but still have a 404 error.

My code in flask

```
@app.route('/user/<string:uid>/subuser/<string:subuser>/key/<string:key>', methods=['DELETE'])
def deleteSubuserKey(uid, subuser, key):
    Log.err("deleteSubuserKey")
    return ...
```

My code in AngularJS

```
$scope.uri = ctrlURL+"S3/user/"+user_id+"/subuser/"+subuser+"/key/"+key;
$http({method: "delete", url: $scope.uri }).
     success(function (data, status) {
                ...
            }).
     error(function (data, status) {
                ...
            });
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This discussion might point you in the right direction: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brian's comment, I solved my issue.
My call was rejected directly by Apache when the slash was encoded.

I've added [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) Directive in my apache conf:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

With the key encoded with :

```
encodeURIComponent(key)
```

It works.